# Run different js on each user visit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I want to load javascript functions on a wordpress site based on user visit, if it's the first time, then one function will run, if its second visit another code will run., I found that using cookies and local storage we can set it, but only track user if visited or not., I want to count the user visit, and based on that run the functions.

```
var first_visit = false;
checkFirstVisit();
function checkFirstVisit(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('was_visited')){
        return;
    }
    first_visit = true;
    localStorage.setItem('was_visited', 1);
}
console.log(first_visit);
```

this code is to track the first visit, How do I make it to track the number of visits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use session storage in PHP (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) to store in a variable whether this is the user's first visit or not.
Then using an if-else statement, display the required code.
The good thing about PHP session storage is that it can retain the storage even after the user closes the browser.

Answer (score 0):

it is the same thing
set a cookie for visiting
if it is not set so it is the first visit so set it to 1
if it is 1 so second visit so set it to 2
if it is n so it is n + 1 visit so incrment n

Comment: How do I store that cookie in localstorage as number of visits?

Comment: localStorage.setItem('visit_counter', count);